# Simple shared library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

1. Is the STD library a shared library or what is it ? out of curiosity .
2. Are there any books describe in detail the shared , static libraries development ?
3. Are there any tutorial ?

p.s (i'm using netbeans , eclipse, anjuta) and the tutorials aren't useful as I'm trying to understand what's actually going on.

Comment: this one is good: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: A very detailed description that is probably way over your head (definitely way over mine, anyway) is a description by Gnu C library maintainer Ulrich Drepper: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my platform (Ubuntu Maverick) it is:

```
g++ test.cpp
ldd a.out

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffee1ff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f18755fd000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f187537a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1875163000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1874de0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1875920000)
```

Note libstdc++.so.6 above.

With [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) creating a shared library is very easy.

1.
Install cmake 2.6 or later.

2.
Create a file test.cpp with the code for your library.

3.
Create a file CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(TEST)
add_library(test SHARED test.cpp)
```

4.
Run cmake to create a makefile:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

5.
Run make to build your shared library.

With CMake you can also generate an Eclipse CDT project using the following command

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

You can also find an interesting article on the topic with further references [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-shobj/).

Answer (score 2):

*1.) Is the STD library a shared library or what is it?*

I have no idea.  Could be either.  Probably both.  Does it matter?  Unless you are dealing with something really exotic like a stand-alone statically linked binary for system rebuilding, as long as the compiler/system knows how to link it in, you are unlikely to be concerned with it.

---

In a nutshell, code can be in static libraries, in which case it's linked into the final (compiled/generated) executable and those binaries can become quite large.  Or it can be in a shared library, in which case the library is dynamically loaded and multiple applications can (theoretically) share one common memory image.  Unless you are doing something that is quite large, and that will be shared across multiple applications, I'd question the wisdom of going with shared libraries.  The additional headaches, especially debugging headaches, are rarely worth it.  And without multiple concurrently running applications, there's no savings...

---

To make a static library, I'd compile a bunch of files into object files...  Than use ***ar*** and ***randlib***.  E.g.:

```
g++ -c foo1.C -o foo1.o
g++ -c foo2.C -o foo2.o
ar -rv libfoo.a foo1.o foo2.o
ranlib libfoo.a
```

Subsequently, I'd just link that library in:

```
g++ testfoo.C -o testfoo -L. -lfoo
```

Note that if you are using multiple libraries, the ordering of ***-lbar1 -lbar2*** on that *(g++ testfoo.C)* command line is important!  It determines which libraries can call functions/methods in other libraries.  Circular dependencies are ***BAD***!

With respect to *foo1.o foo2.o* files to ***ar***, the ordering makes no difference.

---

Dynamic libraries...

Some time ago, under an ancient fedora core 3 system, I was playing around with shared libraries under linux.  Back then, I would compile my shared library, say ***fooLibrary.c***, with:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfooLibrary.so.1 -o libfooLibrary.so.1.0 -fPIC fooLibrary.c -ldl
```

At that time I was playing with LD_PRELOAD, so I had a little script to run my program that did:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=libfooLibrary.so ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ; ./myTestProgram
```

(Note that I did **NOT** want *LD_PRELOAD* set when running commands like *g++*, *ls*, *cd*, etc as I was intercepting system calls.)

(FYI: ***strace*** is also fun to play with...  You should also check out ***ldd*** and ***nm***.)

You may want to look at things like ***dlopen()*** and ***dlsym()*** -- for manually accessing dynamic libraries...

Oh, and the environment variable ***LD_LIBRARY_PATH*** adds directories to the default searchpath for dynamic libraries...

(With respect to debugging, let me just mention that when I intercepted *malloc()*, I found that somewhere inside *dlopen()/dlsym()* were calls to *malloc()*.  Meaning that I needed to use *malloc()* before I could manually load the library that provided the real *malloc()*.  Fun times debugging that one...)

---

PS One more thought:  You may want to review the command-line options to *gcc/g++*.  There's a lot of useful info in there...

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC